# Error when adding Firebase to Chrome extension in JS

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension

I am having trouble making Firebase work in JS, specifically working on an extension.

Here is my Manifest.json

```js
{
"manifest_version": 2,     //required
"version": "1.0",               //required
"name": "Hello World!",   //required
"description": "Learning how to make a chrome extension!",
"icons": {
     "16": "images/puppy16.png",
     "48": "images/puppy48.png",
     "128": "images/puppy.png"
    },
"browser_action":
 {
 "default_icon": "images/puppy.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
 }, 
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'"
  "permissions": [
      "identity",
      "tabs",
       "activeTab",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

And here is my background.js file

```js
 // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "xxxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  rootRef.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}
writeUserData("11", "pete", "p@g.com", "google.com")
```

I am specifically getting an error that states: Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined.

Perhaps the problem is in external libraries?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't imported the firebase SDK in any way. Just putting them in the same folder isn't enough to have your file know about firebase. Add the firebase SDK js file to the scripts part of the manifest, before your background.js script. Say it is named `firebase.js`, your manifest should have this line in it:

```
"scripts": ["firebase.js", "background.js"]
```